# How to input the columns of a matrix as variables to a function we want to plot

Tags: equation-solving, matrix

I have a matrix of my data and I want to use it as an input for my other function for my rest of calculation and plot it without doing it manually. 
Here is my matrix:

\begin{array}{cc}
 100 & 3.27114 \\
 105 & 3.4544 \\
 110 & 3.64229 \\
 115 & 3.83686 \\
 120 & 4.04131 \\
 125 & 4.20915 \\
 130 & 4.38971 \\
 135 & 4.53569\\
 140 & 4.67398\\
 145 & 4.80186 \\
 150 & 4.9105 \\
\end{array}

The first column be the x and second y, now I want to have a table for various value of a function of $\Omega [x,y]$ for given [x,y]matrix.
Or plot $\Omega[x,y]$ vs x for given matrix.

p.s: I originally got the matrix from    FindRoot command:
$Temp[x, y, \mu_ ]:= 
 T /. FindRoot[
    Log[\epsilon ^2 \Gamma BAR[x, y 
         , \mu]/Hubb[x, y, \mu]] == 0, {y, 4}][[1]]$
$Tab10 = Table[{x, Temp[1, x, 0]}, {x, 100, 150, 5}]$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you're asking for?

```
data = {{100, 3.27114}, {105, 3.4544}, {110, 3.64229}, {115, 
3.83686}, {120, 4.04131}, {125, 4.20915}, {130, 4.38971}, {135, 
4.53569}, {140, 4.67398}, {145, 4.80186}, {150, 4.9105}}
Map[Apply[f, #] &, data]
```

Comment: noting the fact that my function has 3 variables and the data table just giving 2 first variables does it work?

Comment: Never mind I got it and yes, I didn’t know about Map command thanks.

Comment: done :D new in this place and thanks for the guideline. @Alan